# Script to open a java application and insert text

Tags: java, javascript, windows, vbscript, applescript

I have a program for my DVR entitled DVRJavaView.jar. The program opens up, requests the ip address, press enter, insert username, press tab, inster password, press enter. I found a website discussing this very issue with code included, however, it is written in applescript and I am using Windows.

The discussion is found here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16253980#16253980

This is the applescript:

```
on run
 do shell script "/usr/bin/open '/Applications/DVRJavaView4.1.jar'"

 tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true)
      repeat until exists window "Please Input DVR address"
           delay 1
      end repeat
      keystroke "millapt.ddns.specoddns.net"
      keystroke return
      repeat until exists button "OK" of window 1
           delay 1 -- wait until the login window is frontmost
      end repeat
      keystroke "user"
      keystroke tab
      delay 0.1
      keystroke "4321"
      delay 0.1
      keystroke return
      repeat until name of window 1 starts with "DVRJavaView"
           delay 1 --wait while the login window is frontmost
      end repeat
      click button 2 of window 1 -- zoom
 end tell
end run
```

I am not very knowledgable about programming, but willing to learn.

Is there any direction anyone could give to help me achieve this script within the Windows environment? I am unsure if I should use VB or Javascript. I don't believe bat files can achieve such things, but I could be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely have to tweak this, but this is the basic idea:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\Program Files\Java\jre[version number]\bin\java.exe C:\DVRJavaView4.1.jar"
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("java")
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "millapt.ddns.specoddns.net"
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "user"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "4321"
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I took your code, did a little bit of research, and was able to modify it to work 100%.

Comment: That's great to hear! You should repost your working code here so others can use it. You can click "edit" below my post and update it so others can learn from your changes.